# OnInfoListener never fires. Ever

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm currently trying to write a simple audio player that streams a URL until the user quits. Nothing fancy really, but I'm trying to use the onInfo method of MediaPlayer to wait for the metadata update flag. I have the following code for creating the media player object.

```
/**
 * Creates a new media player and attempts to prepare it.
 */
private void createPlayer(){
    Log.v(TAG, "Now in createPlayer()");
    if(mPlayer==null){
        Log.i(TAG, "No existing media player found, creating.");
        mPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
        mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mPlayer.setOnInfoListener(new OnInfoListener() {
            public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                Log.w(TAG,"---Got some info!---");
                return false;
            }
        });
        mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Found an existing media player. Doing nothing.");
    }
    try{
        mPlayer.setDataSource(mStreamUri);
        mPlayer.prepareAsync();
        Log.i(TAG, "Just sent the media player a prepareAsync()");
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG,"Caught exception while trying to set up media player.");
    }
}
```

I have yet to see onError fire, but I also have yet to actually get any errors because of the simplicity of my app, but of course onPrepare works fine. I've tried implementing it with the class, as well as an inline method like the above code but nothing happens.

Answer (score -1):

Change your code with this and try again -

```
 mPlayer.prepare();
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot return false in onInfoListener. The android developer says if it returns false, the infoListener seems as if it was not set.

Comment: I wish that was true. I know the documentation says something, but this is Android. Look at the source code: `                if (mOnInfoListener != null) {
                   mOnInfoListener.onInfo(mMediaPlayer, msg.arg1, msg.arg2);
              }`. It doesn't care what you return. It doesn't check it or store it anywhere.